# How to call a function depending on template type in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, model

I have the following hierarchy of class:

```
class Boy : Child
class Girl : Child

template<class T>
class Parent
{
    vector<T> children;
}


class AnnaBoys: public Parent<Boy>
{
 void ProcessChild() { do things specific to Anna boys };
};

class AnnaGirls: public Parent<Girl>
{
 void ProcessChild() { do things specific to Anna girls};
};
```

The two `ProcessChild()` function here are doing unrelated things, not "templetable" in the way `add<T>` could be.

I'm looking to avoid having to create two Anna class and just do this instead:

```
template<class T>
class Anna: public Parent<T>
    {
     void ProcessChild() 
     { 
        if(T is Boys)
         ProcessBoys();
        else
         ProcessGirls();
      };
    };
```

Is there any clean way to do this without doing a dynamic_cast at runtime ?

Thanks.

Comment: Think SFINAE: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can specialize individual member functions without specifying the whole class. In this case:

Header:

```
template<typename T>
class Anna : Parent<T> {
public:
  void ProcessChild() {
    // default implementation (if desired)
  }
};

template<> void Anna<Boy>::ProcessChild();
template<> void Anna<Girl>::ProcessChild();
```

Source file:

```
template<> void Anna<Boy>::ProcessChild() {
  // implementation for boys
}

template<> void Anna<Girl>::ProcessChild() {
  // implementation for girls
}
```

It is possible to have the specialized member functions in the header by declaring them `inline`, if you want to keep things header-only:

```
template<typename T>
class Anna : Parent<T> {
public:
  void ProcessChild() {
    // default implementation (if desired)
  }
};

template<> inline void Anna<Boy>::ProcessChild() {
  // implementation for boys
}

template<> inline void Anna<Girl>::ProcessChild() {
  // implementation for girls
}
```

Thanks to @Deduplicator for spotting that.

Comment: That seems to be what I'm looking for. Does the compiler automatically create instanciation for Anna<Girl> and Anna<Boy> in this case or just when i create the first object ?

Comment: @user2164703: Only for those specialized functions. It's generally a good idea to only declare the explicit specialization in the header, and implement it in an implementation-file. Otherwise, they have to be marked `inline`.

Comment: What @Deduplicator says. It's not really necessary to put the implementation into a source file, but doing so saves a little compile time, and there'll be less weak symbols for the linker to sort out. If you don't want to be a header-only library, doing it is good practice. The `inline` bit is a good point, I should mention that in the answer.