# Partially specialized member function on template classes

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates, model

I have some template classes and I need to implement a specialized member function for the main class. For example, if we have a template class `Parent` and other two template classes `Boy` and `Girl`. I want to implement a member function with specialization for Boy and for Girl. The member function for Girl has one more argument.

Boy and Girl are template class themselves also, so **how do I define TT in this code?**

```
template< typename TT >
class Child
{
    TT age;
};

template< typename TT >
class Boy< TT > : public Child< TT > 
{ ... };

class Girl< TT > : public Child< TT >
{ ... };

template<typename T>
class Parent {
private:
    std::vector< T > children;
//public:
//  void ProcessChild() {
//  }
};

template<> void Parent < Boy< TT > >::ProcessChild( TT age ) { // ??
  // implementation for boys
}

template<> void Parent< Girl< TT > >::ProcessChild( TT age, std::string name ) { // ??
  // implementation for girls
}
```

In this context, T would be a Boy or a Girl and TT would be int or double.

I want two member function specializations for ProcessChild, one for Boy and one for Girl. I can't seem to find the proper syntax for my code, also I can't find any other example where inner class is also a template class. Other examples are specializations of primitive types such as `int` or `double`.

I am also trying something like this:

```
template<>
template< class U >
class Parent < Girl< U > >
{
public:
    template< class TT >
    void ProcessChild( TT age, std::string name )
    {
         //...
    }
};
```

All the code shown here is not compiling. This is one of the errors I am getting: `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Parent<Girl<U> >`

*Extra*: my question is an extension [from this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28569240/3196464). I modified the example quite a bit though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to fully specialize the function then you could explicitly instantiate the function to create a specialization, but that won't work in this case since you can't partially specialize function templates.

In this case, your best bet is probably to pull the non-specialized functionality out into a base class.  Then you can partially specialize `Parent<Boy<TT>>` and `Parent<Girl<TT>>` and have them both derive from the base class:

```
template <typename T>
class ParentBase {
protected:
    std::vector<T> children;
};

template <typename T>
class Parent;

template <typename TT>
class Parent<Boy<TT>> : ParentBase<Boy<TT>> {
public:
    void processChild(TT age) {
      // ...
    }
};

template <typename TT>
class Parent<Girl<TT>> : ParentBase<Girl<TT>> {
public:
    void processChild(TT age, std::string name) {
      // ...
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79342770f98727fa)

Comment: Uh, feels like a bummer to know that. I thought I was only getting the syntax wrong. Your solution seems to solve the issue though, I will try this.

Comment: You most definitely *can* specialise a template member. Just not partially specialise.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Is that actually specialization or is it explicit instantiation?  I guess the difference is fairly moot

Comment: I posted another answer with what I actually did. I understand that your answer is the most elegant one and solves the issue in question, but I didn't want to include more classes.

Answer (score 1):

I will simplify your example.

```
template <typename> struct Foo { void foo() {}; };
```

You can have this:

```
template <> void Foo<int>::foo() {}
template <> void Foo<double>::foo() {}
template <> void Foo<std::vector<int>>::foo()
```

Those would be [explicit specialisations of a class template member function](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec).

But you cannot have this:

```
template <> void Foo<std::vector<K>>::foo() {}
```

because there is no K defined anywhere. What does this K mean? Where should it be defined? If you want to specialise for vectors of *any* type, then K should be a template parameter somewhere. Where?

The obvious choice is

```
template <typename K> void Foo<std::vector<K>>::foo() {}
```

but no, the explicit specialisation syntax does not allow this.

Wait, isn't it a partial specialisation of `Foo::foo`? Nope, there are no partial specialisations of *function* templates, only of class templates. So no luck here either.

You can partially specialise `Foo`:

```
template <typename K> struct Foo<std::vector<K>> { void foo(); };
```

and then the definition

```
template <typename K> void Foo<std::vector<K>>::foo() {}
```

is no longer invalid, but it is not a specialisation anymore either. It is a normal out-of-line definition of a member of `Foo<std::vector<K>>`, which *is* a partial specialisation of `Foo`.

Comment: If I understood correctly your analogy, I would like to have not only a specialization for std::vector, but also one for std::map lets say. Which would relate to Boy<K> and Girl<K>

Comment: @gudé yes, exactly.

Comment: I couldn't actually implement this idea. Would you be so kind to provide a more detailed code?

Comment: Nit sure what the problem is. Replace `Foo` with `Parent`, `std::vector` with `Boy`. Note `foo` is not a template itself, and `ProcessChild` shouldn't be either. The template parameter you are looking for is `K` and it is already there.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up realizing I could only do a simple overloading of the function with specific arguments and using the classes I needed inside the function declaration. It is worth noting that my worry here is to properly encapsulate the member function only. For example, not allowing the user to call for ProcessChild with two arguments when Parent has Boy on its template parameter.

This is what I did, which fails to compile when supposed and succeeds to compile when supposed to:

```
template< typename TT >
class Child
{
    TT age;
};

template< typename TT >
class Boy< TT > : public Child< TT > 
{ ... };

class Girl< TT > : public Child< TT >
{ ... };

template<typename T>
class Parent {
private:
    std::vector< T > children;
public:
template< TT > void Parent < Boy< TT > >::ProcessChild( TT age ) { 
    addChild( *( new Boy< TT >( age ) ) );
}

template<> void Parent< Girl< TT > >::ProcessChild( TT age, std::string name ) { 
  addChild( *( new Girl< TT >( age, name ) ) );
}
};
```

In my specific situation I didn't really have to use template function specialization.